# Gvim Tip to move by n lines?

Tags: vim, scroll, line

Is there anyway I can move up/down in Gvim by n lines ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nj` or `nk` where `n` is the number of lines you want to move. You can also use `:n` to jump to line number `n` as well.

eg. to move 10 lines down you would type `10j`. To move to line 10 you would use `:10` and hit enter.

Comment: scrolling != moving ;) but anyway you're right that's probably what he's looking for... +1!

Answer (score 1):

`:help scrolling` will tell you everything you're asking, like :

```
CTRL-E          Scroll window [count] lines downwards in the buffer.
                Mnemonic: Extra lines.
```

and

```
CTRL-Y          Scroll window [count] lines upwards in the buffer.
```

with `[count]` you can type nCTRL-E for n-lines :)

There are many other possibilities that `:help` will give to you.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl-E</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl-Y</kbd> are the *scroll only keys* (where the cursor stays on the same line/col).

However, for page-down/up line behaviour use <kbd>Ctrl-U</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>

By default the number of lines comes from the `'scroll'` option. You can use the `'scrolloff'` option to always keep *`n`* additional lines in view above/below the cursor line.